# Is it still safe to use snprintf function in C++?

Tags: c++

Confused when trying to research about the use of snprintf in C++. I see some online recommends the use of snprintf over sprintf as below.

```
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s", message);
```

while some online says would need additional check when snprintf is used as below.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    size_t pos = 0;
    int i;
 
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int n = snprintf(buffer + pos, BUF_SIZE - pos, "%s", argv[i]);
        if (n < 0 || n >= BUF_SIZE - pos)
        {
            break;
        }
        pos += n;
    }
}
```

Appreciate your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Regardless of whether it's safe, you're in C++. You have `std::string`. Why aren't you using that instead, rather than worrying about using fixed sized buffers with `NUL`-terminated C-strings and manually adjusted memory offsets? `std::string buffer;` `for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) { buffer += argv[i]; }`. No need for `pos` or `BUF_SIZE` (you could use it to `reserve` space for a larger string to avoid reallocations in common cases, but it's not needed), it just works. `stringstream`s of various types are also an option.

Comment: These  "some online" sites you're referring to. Do they bother *elaborating* on their reasons for why they're telling you to do one or the other, or are they just blanket, blind marching orders? If the latter, might I suggest you find a better reference. Regardless, `std::ostringsteam` is generally a preferable alternative in C++. It handles buffer management, growth, as much (or little) formatting as you desire, etc.

Comment: When confronted with a question like this about code, you should consult [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for the function in question to see what it does, what the parameters are, and the meaning of any value returned from it.

Answer (score 3):

You should instead use [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). It's much safer and easier to use. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Ybx7fM) example.

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  std::string s = fmt::format("I'd rather be {1} than {0}.", "right", "happy");
  fmt::print("{}", s);
}
```

This library is mostly standardized in C++20 as `std::format`, but no standard libraries support the standard version yet.